# How do I replace substrings in an array

Tags: c, for-loop, while-loop

I have a program which replaces a parts of a char array with the contents of another, however it also replaces parts of the array that should not be replaced.

The code below is the code responsible for the replacing of characters in the array.
One character at a time, however when only part of what it is supposed to replace is in an array like `xy` of `xyz` it should leave that alone and look for the next occurrence of `xyz` which it would then replace.

```
i =0;
while(i < 30){
    j=0;
    while(j < k){
        if(carray[i] == aarray[j])
            carray[i] = barray[j];
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}
```

My problem is, that if only a part of what the program is supposed to search and replace for is present it replaces it even though it is not the full word that was meant.

for example:

if I want to replace `xyz` with `abc` in the array of `xyzdefxyzghixy`
then the arrays have the following content:

`aarray[] = {xyz}` 
`barray[] = {abc}`
`carray[] = {xyzdefxyzghixy}`

I get `abcdefabcghiab` as an output and the last two characters `ab` should actually remain `xy`

i.e.

I expect the output to be `abcdefabcghixy`

what have I done wrong here.

NB: please Note that I wish to only use `stdio.h`

All help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The inner loop doesn't check if all of `xyz` can be matched. It just tests each character one by one.

Comment: You are only comparing a single character: you should check the whole sequence of three.

Comment: Your code will replace `x->a, y->b, z->c` anywhere any of these characters appear.

Comment: to use _strstr_ and _memcpy_ simplify the work, see my answer

Comment: Thank you for your Help, I wish to clarify that I wish To only use `stdio.h`

Comment: A [mcve] is required - how did you declare all these variables?

Comment: @Koos I edited my answer to add an other proposal without using strlen/strstr/memcpy

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace only when you find the full substring.

There are useful standard functions :

- *strstr* allows to find a substring in a string
- *memcpy* can be used to replace the old substring by the new one

A proposal :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  if (argc != 4)
    printf("usage : %s <str> <old> <new>\n", *argv);
  else {
    char * old = argv[2];
    char * new = argv[3];
    size_t len = strlen(old);

    if (len != strlen(new))
      fprintf(stderr, "'%s' and '%s' do not have the same length\n", old, new);
    else {
      char * str = argv[1];
      char * p = str;

      printf("'%s' -> ", str);

      /* the loop doing the replacements */
      while ((p = strstr(p, old)) != NULL) {
        memcpy(p, new, len);
        p += len;
      }

      printf("'%s'\n", str);
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wextra -Wall r.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
usage : ./a.out <str> <old> <new>
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out xyzdefxyzghixy xyz abc
'xyzdefxyzghixy' -> 'abcdefabcghixy'
```

---

**Edit**

> NB: please Note that I wish to only use stdio.h

Can be :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  if (argc != 4)
    printf("usage : %s <str> <old> <new>\n", *argv);
  else {
    char * old = argv[2];
    char * new = argv[3];
    char * str = argv[1];

    /* check old and new have the same length */
    char * pold, * pnew;

    for (pold = old, pnew = new; *pold && *pnew; ++pold, ++pnew)
      ;

    if (*pold || *pnew)
      fprintf(stderr, "'%s' and '%s' do not have the same length\n", old, new);
    else {
      printf("'%s' -> ", str);

      char * pstr = str;

      /* the loop doing the replacements */
      while (*pstr) {
        /* check if substring */
        char * pold = old;
        char * psubstr = pstr;

        while (*pold && (*pold == *psubstr)) {
          pold += 1;
          psubstr += 1;
        }

        if (*pold == 0) {
          /* substring, replacement */
          pnew = new;

          while (*pnew)
            *pstr++ = *pnew++;
        }
        else
          pstr += 1;
      }

      printf("'%s'\n", str);
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

As you can see this is a bad choice, it is very easy to understand what the previous version does, this is not the case with that version